# How to add leading padding to UILabel in UIStackView IOS

Tags: ios, uilabel, constraints, uistackview

I need your help in adding the **leading space only to UIlabel** which is placed in **UIStackview**. I tried setting constraints but due to UIStackview autolayout feature, it is not allowing me to do. Also, I tried keeping label in UIView but in that case I am not getting the whole lines of label.

[image]

Does anybody know the solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that as Apple documentation says that you can only give position and size to the stack view and the stack view will take care of rest of the things.

**Apple Documentation says:**

[image]

Comment: Ok. Then Can you suggest me other way to implement this functionality.

Comment: Can't you leave stack view ??? Is there any specific reason for using it??

Comment: Actually , I need UIStackView for auto adjusting the size of Cell when ImageView is getting hide in few feeds.

Comment: For adjusting cell height you can use UITableViewAutomaticDimension. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok. I can try this.